# How do I tell django "{% if request.get_full_path|stringify *ends in a number* %}"?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Trying to make an if statement in my template. How do I tell django `{% if request.get_full_path|stringify *ends in a number*  %}`? So the `get_full_path` string would be something like `/news/324/`. This should equal to `True` in the if statement. `{% else %}` would be a string with just: `/news/`

Any idea if I can do this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this?

Comment: Will it be better to move logic to view?

Comment: @Sayse if it ends in a number then that means it's a post. If it doesn't then it's just on the homepage. Because of this I only want to show sorting buttons (hot, new, top etc) on the homepage where the list of posts are. Alexander I don't think so as it's just a matter of showing/hiding some elements.

Comment: I still don't understand, if its a post you'd need a detail page, if its a list you'd have a list page which includes your sorting arguments. Why do both of these use the same template?

Comment: And even if you are using the same parent template, there will be plenty of other things available for you to tell the difference; for example, your detail view will have the object available in the context, whereas the index won't.

Comment: Thanks Daniel I just tried `{% if lst %}` (a context I pass to my homepage) and that works perfect.

Comment: I usually pass `is_home: True` to the context and anything else like `is_post: True` if needed.